# Globalization ASP.NET MVC Currency Output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, currency, globalization

Imagine I wanted to display two values in a view.

Firstly I wanted to display a US revenue figure in dollars.
I then wanted to display an EU revenue figure in euros.

Lets say the US revenue was 1234.56 
The EU revenue was 5678.90

For someone who is viewing the system with the culture en-US (ie American), I want the output to be the following:

US Revenue: $1,234.56
EU Revenue: €5,678.90

For someone who is viewing the system with the culture de-DE (ie German), I want the output to be the following:

US Revenue: $1.234,56
EU Revenue: €5.678,90

In other words, I want the format of the number (and everything else) to be determined by the current culture, and I want to be able to specify the currency.

Is there any way to modify the .ToString("c") so that you can specify the currency (without changing the culture)? If not, what are the other options?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload of ToString that takes two parameters:

```
        double value = 1234.5;
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        return value.ToString("c", cultureInfo.NumberFormat);
```

This will take the culture of the country you specify and format the numbers accordingly.